# Error detecting performace of CRC-8 vs Fletcher-16

Tags: checksum, crc

I have an application where I'm currently using a Fletcher-16 checksum for error detection. Computational speed is important.

I am wondering though, if a CRC-8 algorithm (using a lookup-table) would catch as many or even more errors than a Fletcher-16 checksum would?

I can spare the additional 256-bytes needed for a lookup-table, which seems to be a fair trade for faster computational speed. A CRC-8 lookup-table algorithm would definitely be faster than any Fletcher-16 algorithm.

Searching on the web for this topic seems to only yield scholarly results, which honestly is beyond my comprehension.

Can anyone shed a light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theresa C. Maxino ; Philip J. Koopman, "The Effectiveness of Checksums for Embedded Control Networks", in [*IEEE Transactions on Dependable and Secure Computing*, vol. 6, issue 1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/tocresult.jsp?isnumber=4781520), March 2009:

> *CRC-8, CRC-9, and CRC-10 all perform better than Fletcher-16 for code word lengths less than 128, 256, and 512 bits, respectively.*

So if the codeword / message length to be protected is less than 128 bits then CRC-8 may be better than Fletcher-16.

(Note than not all CRC polynomials are equal: some are much worse than others. For CRC-8 the consensus seems to be on 0xEA; see for example "[Cyclic Redundancy Code (CRC) Polynomial Selection For Embedded Networks](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/roses/dsn04/koopman04_crc_poly_embedded.pdf)" by Philip Koopman and Tridib Chakravarty, 2004.)

Comment: Thanks! Took a while to get through the literature. Wish they had more detailed data on smaller code word sizes (where there is the most variability in performance between different techniques), as the performance of checksums tended to almost level off at larger code word sizes.